# NumberFormatException get average

Tags: java, arrays, numberformatexception

Design and implement a program that reads a series of 10 integers from the user and prints their average. Read each input value as a string, and then attempt to convert it to an integer using the Integer.parseInt method. If this process throws a NumberFormatException (meaning that the input is not a valid number), print an appropriate error message and prompt for the number again. Continue reading values until 10 valid integers have been entered.

Input
•   10 integers inputed from the user through the keyboard
Output
•   Prints the average of the number
•   Error message
o   If the thing that is entered is not an integer
Process
•   Import Scanner class
•   Read in each integer value
o   Convert integer using integer.parseInt method
•   Create exception
o   Throws NumberFormatException
   Not valid
   Print error message

So I am currently designing this and I have no where to begin on the coding. How do I incorporate the numberformatexception and the parseint?

EDIT

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumAverage {

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    //int a,b;
    int[] numbers = new int [10];

    Scanner numreader = new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 10 num");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            numbers[i] = numreader.nextInt();
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(s)
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException numfo)
    {
        System.out.println(numfo.getMessage() + "cannot be converted to integer");
    }
```

}
}

So how can I get the numbers from my array to be parseInted.

Comment: [What have you done?](http://www.whathaveyoudone.com)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions. Hint: Posting your assignment without showing any effort to solve the problem yourself is a quick way to collect downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 1):

is this homework?

[Exception Handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)

[Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the part with the conversion is the one that's giving you headaches.

You can use a  `try-catch` clause:

```
int a;
try{
    a = Integer.parseInt(aString);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("An exception has been thrown. " + aString + 
         " is not a valid number");
}
```

This is the part that takes a string, tries to convert it to a number, and if an exception is thrown, it catches it and prints a message. An exception will be thrown in case the `String` cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Well how can I use this for the numbers that are read into the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "writer's block," use top-down abstract programming:

```
REPEAT
    read a string;
    IF converted to an integer THEN
       ...
    ENDIF;
UNtIL ten integers have been read
```

And then make the code concrete.